# Java- Why is my recursive Draw tree method not outputting correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree, heap

I implemented a heap using an array and i'm trying to draw a tree out of the elements in the array. Here is my method.

```
public void DrawTree(Job[] a,int index,int pre_space){
    for (int i=0;i<pre_space;i++)
           System.out.print(" ");

System.out.print(a[index].getName()+":"+index );

if (2*index<=element_count&&2*index+1<=element_count){ //if it has both children
        System.out.println();

    for (int i=0;i<pre_space;i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

    System.out.print("/");
    System.out.println("\\");

        DrawTree(a,2*index,pre_space-8);
    DrawTree(a,2*index+1,3);

    }

else if (2*index<=element_count){ //if it only has a left child

System.out.println();

for (int i=0;i<pre_space;i++)
            System.out.print(" ");

    System.out.println("/");
        DrawTree(a,2*index,pre_space-3);

     }


    }
```

I am outputting the index as well for understandability. Here is the output I got:

```
          whateve:1
          /\
  Robin:2
  /
Roudy:4   Romy:3
```

Romy should be on the same line as Robin, and from what I understand, when I call the DrawTree method for the right child(Romy) it will backtrack to the appropriate line.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you start from the left side -> right side, so `System.out.println();` will add some additional lines before you draw the right side.

Comment: Yes, but shouldn't it backtrack before it whenever I call the second DrawTree?

Comment: backtrack didn't related here, the order of backtrack is left leaf -> parent -> right leaf ... and you already output some lines before you backtrack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, the scheme you are using is a pre-order traversal, so for example if we have a tree :

```
              1
             / \
            2   3
           / \
          4   5
```

When you traverse to node 2, you output some additional lines before you can go to node 3.

The order is 1 -> output some line ->2 -> output some lines -> 4 -> 5 ->3, so at node 3, we now has at least 2 lines between node 1 and 3.

So what you should do is using an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> lines`, with each element `ArrayList<String>` in `lines` represent one line.

***Note***: this problem is **far complicated** than your current implementation as between each level of the tree, we need to give enough space to display all of its successors. So you need to pre-calculate the necessary space (depending on the size of the sub-tree at each node) before print them out.

Comment: @user189 depends on how well you do the BFS, as you should know who is the parent of the current node, so it is a little bit tricky